# What event in dataGridView triggers on every data loading?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have some functions that changes the dataGridView's source.

What event can I bind to dataGridView in a way that for any changes in source triggers the event-function?

Or need I call a function in all other functions that load data to the source?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the event [`OnDataSourceChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.ondatasourcechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).